# Subdomain on another server cPanel A Record & Cloudflare

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have created an A record to point to another server for a subdomain to be hosted separately from the actual domain name.

I created this on cPanel but I also have Cloudflare enabled. I subdomain doesn't seem to resolve, do I need to create an A record on Cloudflare as well? Are there any particular dns tools I can use to debug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your DNS will be hosted with Cloudflare, you must create an `A RECORD` within Cloudflare and then within cPanel you must make a subdomain or in WHM another account. There are no DNS entries required within cPanel because your DNS is not managed by it.

Adding an add-on or subdomain within cPanel will setup the virtual host file to work with the A record you are pointing to the server.

*6 Step Process setting up subdomain in cPanel*

1. Login to cPanel
2. Scroll down to domains and click subdomains.
3. Fill in the subdomain entry, with just the alias of the subdomain.
4. Select the correct domain for the subdomain if you have multiples attached to your account.
5. Assign a working root for the subdoman.
6. Click Create.

*7 Step Cloudflare Process in creating a subdomain using A RECORD pointing to IP address:*

1. Login to Cloudflare
2. Use the drop-down menu in the upper left of your screen and click your domain that you want to install the subdomain on.
3. Click the DNS icon at the top of the screen.
4. Select `A` using the drop-down options
5. Add the subdomain in `NAME`
6. Add the IP address of your cPanel hosting in the box labeled IPv4 Address.
7. Leave TTL as automatic and CloudFlare enabled or disabled if you like, click `Add Record` button.
8. Optional step, if you server also has an IPv6 IP address then repeat steps 4-7 but use an AAAA record with your server IPv6 IP.

LAST BUT LEAST... WAIT... DNS changes can take several hours to take effect (1-72 hours).

Comment: Ok thanks, just added it on cloudflare, I previously added an A record in the domain cPanel for the subdomain will that cause any issues? Because the domain and subdomain have different ips

Comment: 5. *Add the subdomain in NAME* -> is this like `sub.domain.ext` or just `sub`

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic CNAME requires just the sub domain name, if you add `subdomain.example.com` as the CNAME then your actually creating `subdomain.example.com.example.com` So just add `subdomain`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the above, when you are creating the subdomain, you should probably add it to /public_html root folder (easier to access and set up)

For what it's worth, when I add subdomains in Cloudflare, I always turn off the orange cloud, then confirm it's resolving correctly, then enable the SSL on the subdomain - then later when it's all working fine, I re-enable the orange cloud.

Also, once you've followed those steps, you can track the DNS updates here (just enter your sub.domain.name)

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/