# Is it necessary to edit DNS settings at registrar when using CloudFlare?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdomain, nameserver, cloudflare

I need to point a subdomain to a different web hosting service. The domain is registered with my registrar, the DNS is managed by CloudFlare, and the hosting is managed by a third party hosting company. From my research it seems possible but I could not figure out how to do it. I found a solution here:

[Subdomain on another server cPanel A Record & Cloudflare](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106032/subdomain-on-another-server-cpanel-a-record-cloudflare)

...but there is one thing I did not understand. I wanted to ask it there but it requires 50 rept. to comment.

I pointed my subdomain to my hosting company in my DNS settings on CloudFlare. My question is: Do I need to do something at the domain registrar company, since it has its own domain management pages?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your DNS hosted?    Where can you create `CNAME` and `A` records?  It should be the same place that your `NS` records point at your domain registrar.   Without that information we can't give you very specific instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DNS for your domain is being managed by CloudFlare (that is, your domain's nameservers are set to CloudFlare's nameservers), then you do not have to update any DNS settings at your registrar, only at CloudFlare.

The DNS management pages at your registrar take effect *only* when your nameservers are set to your registrar's nameservers. Since your nameservers are set to CloudFlare, any changes you make to your DNS settings at your registrar do not have any effect on your domain.